# Do parent-child process relationship and pipe exist in distributed systems?

Tags: concurrency, pipe, ipc, distributed-computing

In The Linux Programming Interface by Kerrisk

> In  the  discussion  so  far,  we  have  talked  about  using  **pipes** 
>   for  communication between **a parent and a child process**. However,
>   pipes can be used for communication between **any two (or more) related
>   processes**, as long as the pipe was created by a common ancestor before
>   the series of fork() calls that led to the existence of the processes.

In distributed systems,

- does the relationship of parent-child processes or "related" processes exist between processes running on different machines in the distributed systems?
- does pipe  exist as a way for communication between processes  running on different machines in the distributed systems?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A concept of parent-child processes is not practical to design against in distributed environment, since a single process is not reliable.

Two patterns that are commonly used instead:

- **Service discovery**, a way for a process detect other processes it depends upon.
- **RPC**, to communicate with other processes over the network.